# JWrapper splash screen not disappearing on El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, jwrapper

I've been using JWrapper for about a year now with no problems.

Now, on one user's machine with Mac OS X El Capitan, almost everytime I release a new version of my software the JWrapper splash screen on first launch never goes away until the system is rebooted.

I've had look at the logs and see nothing suspicious and I see that my application seems to launch correctly.

Suggestions welcome, this is not a proper SO question I know but JWrapper people tell that they are experimenting with support for the Free version on SO, thus I'm basically trying to get them to answer this.

Comment: Not much support from JWrapper people for Free version users...

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this exact same bug and have for a long time now.

EDIT: According to the people behind JWrapper, this issue should be fixed in the newest version.